# Can't wake up Windows 10 from sleep with one single key press on a USB keyboard; needs to press multiple times

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, sleep, wake-up

**Problem details:**

I can wake up my Windows 10 desktop computer from sleep with my USB keyboard/Logitech wireless mouse, but the only issue is that with the keyboard, sometimes I am not able to wake up the PC with only one single keypress.

Instead, I need to keep pressing the key multiple times or press different keys until it finally responds and wakes up. I did some research, some people are also facing similar issues but haven't found a solution yet. It seems that the issue only happen on my machine after it has been on sleep for some time; if it was just put to sleep shortly before trying to wake up with the keyboard, it seems to always respond to one single keypress.

**System specs:**

```
Edition Windows 10 Home
Version 21H2
OS build    19044.1645
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4170.0
```

**Sleep settings:**

```
Hybrid sleep: on
Hibernation: off
```

Any idea what might be the root cause?

Comment: Try pressing the Fn key. That should wake up the computer.

Comment: @John Thanks for your comment but: 
1. it's not a laptop computer and I'm using a USB keyboard that doesn't necessarily have an Fn key. Mine happen to have Fn but; 
2. it's not that I'm not able to wake up the PC from sleep, it's that sometimes I can't wake it up with a single keypress. I have to press multiple times to be able to do it. And just to confirm Fn doesn't behave any differently than other keys.

Comment: I was able to do this on a desktop by moving the mouse or pressing enter on the particular customer computer I was using. So what key will probably depend on your computer. Is there any documentation with the keyboard?

Comment: @John Ultimately any specific key works for my desktop and keyboard, be it Enter/Shift/alphabet keys, but I would likely have to press it multiple times to finally see the PC wake up when the PC has been sleeping for quite some time, say, overnight.

It behaves like there's something on the system level/BIOS level to make sure you were not accidentally pressing a key, so it wants to see you pressing multiple times/multiple keys. 

And no documentation for the keyboard; it's just a general use USB keyboard.

Comment: I don't think there is much you can do. Generic BIOS / Keyboard depends on the OS to do the wok.